# C++ vs Java in Android

Tags: java, android, c++, opengl-es

I'm interesting in start a game development. I currently did some openGL in C++, but now I'm looking for the options that offers Android, and I have found people who developes his games using Native code (C++) and others that use Java...

So I don't really know which is the main difference. I read that many people has experience using C++ and prefers this one to don't have to learn new things using java... but I don't think this is the main reason.

What are the main differences developing a game using C++ or Java? Perfomance? Scalability? Posibilities?

Also, do you recommend to start the game development using OpenGL?

Comment: Consider using `Renderscript` http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/introducing-renderscript.html

Comment: Just to make sure you understand the difference -- Android uses OpenGL ES, which is a slimmed down version of OpenGL.

Comment: Very detailed explanation of Android NDK by a Google Android Developer in this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yorhsSPFG4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest using whichever language you are more comfortable with. A game is never a small project, and since you are new to the process (judging by this question) you will probably not be concerned with any performance differences or anything like that.

To answer your questions:

**Performance**

see [C++ vs Java Performance](http://blog.cfelde.com/2010/06/c-vs-java-performance/), [Android: Java, C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901488/android-java-c-or-c), etc.

**Possibilities**

There is nothing inherit that C++ can do and Java can't, or vice versa when it comes to your goal.

**Scalability**

Not sure what you are asking with this one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Then, if both has the same possibilities, why people select one or other? Only because they know more about one in particular? I'm beginner in game development but I would like to start with the best options, even if it is harder. Thanks again

Comment: Pretty much. If it was up to me I would do C++ since that was my first and preferred language. Plus I already know OpenGL using the native C++ and don't need to bother with the Java wrappers. Not sure how it is on mobile devices, but most of the prominent game engines, and the associated APIs, for PC use are in C++ making it easier as well (look at any AAA game. I almost guarantee it is C++, PC or Console). Though this may be different on Mobile devices. On the other hand, some developers may have only ever used Java (or think it is 'cleaner' or 'easier', both are subjective) and use it.

Answer (score 6):

C++ can perform better than Java (don't believe the naysayers, do your own benchmarks), but there is more support for Java on Android. In the end it depends on how intensive your app is going to be and how much battery it is going to drain. If it is extremely intensive, go with C++ because you can do more with less. If it doesn't matter, then go with Java.

Answer (score 0):

at the end it doesn't matter sense if you use c++ you will need to learn all those frameworks used for android development, if you use java you will learn java and openGL is the same in all languages so just go with c++ if you are a c++ developer

> Also, do you recommend to start the game development using OpenGL?

you should not start with OpenGL not that you can't but I would sagest something like SFML witch will teach you a lot about graphics programming then you can move to OpenGL

Comment: Why do you suggest not starting with OpenGL?

Comment: Because it is hard (talking about OpenGL 3+) for your first tringle program you need to learn about shaders so basically you need to learn a lot before you even start programming with openGL that's why I prefer SFML it will tech you all the concepts about graphics programming then OpenGL wont seem so hard I did not started with it and I don't know someone that did if you want to talk with professional  graphics programmers  then hang over to the SFML chat ask them https://chat.sfml-dev.org/